# Can't call custom method in class that implements Comparator

Tags: java, priority-queue, comparator

I am having this issue where I have a `PiorityBlockingQueue` to sort the items in it. The are several options the user can sort the items being added into the queue.

The one I'm stuck at is trying to order the queue by the most occurences of an `Item`.

The choice of the comparison is determined in the constructor of `MyQueue`. But the counts of (eg. Low, Medium, High) isnt determined until later. When it is determined, I wanted to call the `update(String lst)` method from `ItemComparator` to update the `hashmap` so that the sorting is correct.

So my issue is I can't call that method. I know I'm missing something but I can't figure it out. Any help? Maybe there a better design than what I doing now?

```
 public class ItemComparator implements Comparator<Item>
    {        
         public void update(String lst){
             test = lst;
         }

         public int compare(Item o1, Item o2) {
            HashMap<String,Integer> priority = new HashMap<>();
            priority.put("LOW", 1);
            priority.put("MEDIUM", 2);
            priority.put("HIGH", 3);

            if (priority.get(o1.getPriority()) > priority.get(o2.getPriority())) {
                return -1;
            }
            if (priority.get(o1.getPriority()) < priority.get(o2.getPriority())) {
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
         }    
    }
```

This statement wont work from this class comparator.update(aString);

```
public class MyQueue implements AQueue{

    private Comparator<Ticket> comparator;
    private PriorityBlockingQueue<Ticket> listOfTickets;
    private String policy;

    BlockingQImpl(String processingPolicy) throws InvalidDataException {
        setPolicy(processingPolicy.toUpperCase());
        setComparator(policy);
    }

    private void setComparator(String policy) throws InvalidDataException {
        if (policy.equals("THIS")) {
            comparator = new ItemComparator(countString);
        } 
        listOfTickets = new PriorityBlockingQueue<>(10, comparator);
    }

    public void addList(int id) {
        ticks.add(id)
        comparator.update(aString);
    }
}
```

Comment: its in one of the methods in MyQueue, I've updated to show it

Comment: Your code still doesn't look right. `BlockingQImpl` looks like a constructor but doesn't match the class name `MyQueue`. Can you make sure that you are posting the right code? And also the error message.

Comment: Is the `update` method in `ItemComparator`. If yes then probably you need to change `private Comparator<Ticket> comparator;` to `private ItemComparator comparator;`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the compilation error at `comparator.update(aString);` right?

It is because you have declared `comparator` as `Comparator<Ticket>`, that means, you are "seeing" it as a `Comparator`, and in a `Comparator`, there is no `update()` method.

You should declare it as `ItemComparator`

i.e.

```
private ItemComparator comparator;
```